# login button browser resize

Tags: css, jquery-ui

i am having problem with re-size browser window
when i re-size the window customer login button does not come within the body

how to fix that issue i have given margin on it thats the problem

```
<div class="inner clearfix" style="margin-left: 1000px;">
 <div class="logo">
 <a href="" class="customerLogin"> Customer Login </a> 
</div> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/1/embedded/result/
http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/1/

Answer (score 1):

You gave it a fixed margin:

```
margin-left: 1000px;
```

So it'll be 1000px from the left all the time. Change it to the following, for example:

```
float: right;
```

Comment: thank you similarly the bottom div also goes out of range how to fix it <div class="row-fluid marketing" style="margin-top: 27px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 100px;">
        <div class="span8">

        <section id="main" style="background-color: #646464; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="inner clearfix" style="background-color: white;">
              <span style="color: #06546a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: white;">Defie Cloud Buisness Solutions</span>helps companies of all sizes to enhance business op

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to make it aligned to the right:

```
<div style="margin-right: 50px; text-align: right;" class="inner clearfix">
    <div class="logo">
    <a class="customerLogin" href="">     
        Customer Login
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you similarly the bottom div also goes out of range how to fix it <div class="row-fluid marketing" style="margin-top: 27px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 100px;"> <div class="span8"> <section id="main" style="background-color: #646464; padding: 0px;"> <div class="inner clearfix" style="background-color: white;"> <span style="color: #06546a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: white;">Defie Cloud Buisness Solutions</span>helps companies of all sizes to enhance business op